# Do I need to use maven in order to use Spring Boot, or is there a jar?

Tags: spring, maven, jar, spring-boot

I have a Spring project which currently doesn't use maven, I just use jars for my libraries.

I'm trying to use spring boot but it's not in any of my spring libraries so I went to look for a jar, but there doesn't seem to be any. Is this true? Do I need to use maven or some equivalent to use Spring Boot?

Comment: You need to for your sanity, just like you need to use version control.

Comment: You *get* to use Maven :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download all the jars you need from [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot). Just click on the artifact and the version you want, and you'll see **Download (JAR)** link.

Comment: Yes this is what I normally do but in this case a lot of them are missing for example  spring boot starter parent http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.3.RELEASE

Any idea why this would be?

Comment: There is no JAR to be downloaded for spring-boot-starter-parent, I think it's just a pre-configured POM file that users can use as parent POM in their spring boot projects. I don't see a reason for your project not to work if you add all other necessary JARs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can download the jars, the [autoconfigure jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure) is the one will configure all stuff for you "boot" the application. BUT you'll need download manually, all jars, dependencies, since the starters are just pom's to do this work for you. For you sanity it's way better to use a dependency management tool, such [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). They are easy to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both ways but the safest and correct way is to go for maven as it works on dependency based.

You can use the below code just by changing the version of boot.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```